# Second set of tabs in an Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I want to add a second row of tabs to my Android application on the second fragment accessed from the ActionBar tabs.

[image]

Tab 1 shows fragment 1.

Tab 2 shows fragment 2 but I would like fragment 2 to have a second row of tabs so it will show fragment a or b.

But it seems like fragments within fragments cannot be done and an ActionBar submenu can't be switched on or off. I have also tried with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter with a TabHost and a ViewPager which displays the tabs fine but does not display the fragments. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @richy         Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the new Design Support Library ....
In your second fragment you can use TabLayout introduced in design support library 22 . Which is same as Actionbar tabs.

So just add the `TabLayout` in your second fragment XML.

And TabLayout has a method `setUpWithViewPager()`. So you can easily setup your tabs.

I hope it helps you.
here is the reference http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html